# Wordpress url rewrite add_rewrite_rule category, subcategory, tag

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite my urls, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong..

**What I want:**

I created a custom post type called babynames in babynames I created 2 subcategories (boys and girls) Its also posible to filter on the first letter, I i'm using the tag functionality for it.

**This is what i want, but not working**

site.com/babynames/

site.com/babynames/a/

site.com/babynames/a/page/2

site.com/babynames/boys/

site.com/babynames/boys/a/ (this is the url with the tag)

site.com/babynames/boys/a/page/2

site.com/girls/boys/

site.com/girls/boys/a/ (this is the url with the tag)

site.com/girls/boys/a/page/2

And the detail page is site.com/name

**What I got right now is almost working**

The boys and girls urls are working, onlt the babynames/a/ is nog working..

```
add_rewrite_rule('babynames/$([a-z]+)?$', 'index.php?category_name=babynames&tag=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('babynames/([a-z]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?category_name=babynames&tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');

add_rewrite_rule('babynames/boys/?([a-z]+)/?$', 'index.php?category_name=boys&tag=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('babynames/boys/?([a-z]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?category_name=boys&tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');

add_rewrite_rule('babynames/girls/?([a-z]+)/?$', 'index.php?category_name=girls&tag=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('babynames/girls/?([a-z]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?category_name=girls&tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

```
add_rewrite_rule('babynamen/([^/])/?$', 'index.php?category_name=babynamen&tag=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('babynamen/([^/])/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?category_name=babynamen&tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');

add_rewrite_rule('babynamen/jongensnamen/([a-z]+)/?$', 'index.php?category_name=jongensnamen&tag=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('babynamen/jongensnamen/([a-z]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?category_name=jongensnamen&tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');

add_rewrite_rule('babynamen/meisjesnamen/([a-z]+)/?$', 'index.php?category_name=meisjesnamen&tag=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('babynamen/meisjesnamen/([a-z]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?category_name=meisjesnamen&tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
```